# A button that will give me a file of inputs

Tags: c#, visual-studio, user-interface

I have a GUI with 10 rows and 4 columns. the purpose for it is for me to enter in inputs into each box, and at the bottom, click the submit button where it will give me a file with all the inputs. The problem I am having is how can I code my "button" to do this? Help?

I am also having problems with my menustrip. Seems like everything is correct, but my visual won't accept it. Is there something wrong with my code?

-- It is my first time working with C# and visual, so any help will be much appreciated!

```
Public partial class Form 1 : Form
{


int count;
    Form mdiChild;
    TextBox editTextBox;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        count = 1;
    }

    private void newToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mdiChild = new Form();
        mdiChild.Text = “Document” + count.ToString();
        mdiChild.MdiParent = this;
        editTextBox = new TextBox();
        editTextBox.Multiline = true;
        editTextBox.Dock = Dockstyle.Fill;
        mdiChild.Controls.Add(editTextBox);
        mdiChild.Show();
        count++;
    }

    private void openToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();

        ofd.Title = “Open a Text File”;
        ofd.Filter = “Text File (*.txt)|*.txt|All Files (*.*)|*.*”;

        DialogResult dr = ofd.ShowDialog();
        If (dr == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamREader(ofd.FileName);

            Form activeChildForm = this.ActiveMdiChild;

            If (activeChildForm != null)
                 activeTextBox.Text = sr.ReadToEnd();

        {
            System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamREader(ofd.FileName);

            Form activeChildForm = this.ActiveMdiChild;

            If (activeChildForm != null)
                 activeTextBox.Text = sr.ReadToEnd();

            sr.Close();
        }
    }
}

    private void saveToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();

        sfd.Title = “Save a Text File”;
        sfd.Filter = “Text File (*.txt)|*.txt|All Files (*.*)|*.*”;

        DialogResult dr = sfd.ShowDialog();
        If (dr == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(sfd.FileName);

            Form activeChildForm = this.ActiveMdiChild;

            If (activeChildForm != null)
            {
                TextBox activeTextBox = (TextBox)activeChildForm.ActiveControl;

                If (activeTextBox != null)
                     sw.Write(activeTextBox.Text);

                sw.Close();
        }
    }
}

    private void cutToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form activeChildForm = this.ActiveMdiChild;

        if (activeChildForm != null)
        {
            TextBox activeTextBox = (TextBox)activeChildForm.ActiveControl;
            if (activeTextBox != null)
                 activeTextBox.Cut();
        }
    }

private void copyToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form activeChildForm = this.ActiveMdiChild;

        if (activeChildForm != null)
        {
            TextBox activeTextBox = (TextBox)activeChildForm.ActiveControl;
            if (activeTextBox != null)
                 activeTextBox.Copy();
        }
    }

private void pasteToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form activeChildForm = this.ActiveMdiChild;

        if (activeChildForm != null)
        {
            TextBox activeTextBox = (TextBox)activeChildForm.ActiveControl;
            if (activeTextBox != null)
                 activeTextBox.Paste();
        }
    }

private void exitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String file_name = “C:\\test1.txt”;

        System.IO.StreamReader objReader;
        objReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(file_name)l

        textBox1.Text = objReader.ReadToEnd();

        objReader.Close();
    }

    Private void helpToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start (“    “);
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code. As it is now, you've pasted your entire form, and half of it is missing at that.

Comment: I actually haven't done the button one since I do not know how to start out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should put the code in your button click. you might have to modify to code since your question was a bit confusing. I wasn't sure if you wanted the input from controls or the gridview so I wrote the code for gridview

```
    namespace Test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        const string path = @"C:\Kelimeler\Test.txt";
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Server=.;Database=Northwind; UID=sa;PWD=1234");
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select ShipperID, CompanyName,Phone FROM Shippers", conn);

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dtSource = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dtSource);

            dt.DataSource = dtSource;

            if (dt != null)
            {
                if (!File.Exists(path))
                {
                    File.Create(path);
                }

                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dt.Rows)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < dt.ColumnCount; i++)
                    {
                        File.AppendAllText(path, row.Cells[i].Value.ToString());
                        File.AppendAllText(path, ", ");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets say If you are displaying it in a grid and you use a Winform Grid.And you somehow enter the info in your GUI
on behind of your click event that is button click event add this code

```
System.Data.DataTable GridToDT = new System.Data.DataTable();

                GridToDT = (System.Data.DataTable)GridMain.DataSource;
```

This code gives you a datatable in which all the information is displayed Now using this table you can do anything you want ..that is either save it in a database or Write it to Excel anything...hope this helps Mark as answer if you feel so.